finding the transfer equation of $\frac{H(s)}{Q_d(s)}$ in liquid control system with hydraulic integral controller.

On problem B-4-10
So my attempt is as follows:
from the liquid control system we have
$(q_d+q_i-q_o)dt=Cdh$ since  $R=\frac{h}{q_0}$  and $R=0.5$ then $q_0=2h$.
By the equibilirium system on the lever we have $x*a=(a+b)*h$ hence $x=4h$
By assuming that the initial condition is 0 then by laplace transforms we have $X(s)=4H(s)$ and $Q_d(s)+Q_i(s)-2H(s)=2sH(s)$. Since $dy/dt=4x$ then $Y(s)=\frac{4X(s)}{s}$ .but $q_i=-y$ then $Q_i(s)=-Y(s)$. Hence $Q_i(s)=-4\frac{X(s)}{{s}}=-16\frac{H(s)}{s}$ hence we have $Q_d(s)=(2s+2+\frac{16}{s})H(s)$ thus the transfer function is $\frac{H(s)}{Q_d(s)}=\frac{s}{2s^2+2s+16}$ however according to the official solution the answer is $\frac{s}{2s^2+2s+1}$ . So i believe my step is wrong at this equation $x*a=(a+b)*h$ as it should be $x*(a+b)=h*a$. However, i could not think of any arguments that can support the latter, so in what way is the preceding equation wrong?Any help is appreciated.
